# SQL - How to display only certain values of the Count Aggregate Function?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

what I'm trying to do is to only display only rows with a count value greater than 3.

```
select pharm_name, count(1) as "Number of Staff"
from pharmacies p, pharmacy_staff_store pss
where p.pharm_id = pss.pharmacy_id
group by pharm_name;
```

For example this query might return me 5 rows where under the "Number of Staff" it'll say for instance 5,4,3,2,1 but I only want it to return me those rows where the count is 3 and above. Is there a feasible way to do this?

Comment: Simply use `HAVING` clause which any worthwhile SQL tutorial includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the having :

```
select pharm_name, count(1) as "Number of Staff"
from pharmacies p, pharmacy_staff_store pss
where p.pharm_id = pss.pharmacy_id    
group by pharm_name
having count(1) > 3
```

or you can write in this way:

```
select * from (
select pharm_name, count(1) as x
from pharmacies p, pharmacy_staff_store pss
where p.pharm_id = pss.pharmacy_id
group by pharm_name)
where x>3
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept it as answer by clicking the Tick on my answer

Answer (score 0):

First dont use `WHERE join`
Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Then use `HAVING` to filter from the result.

```
SELECT pharm_name, 
       Count(1) AS "Number of Staff" 
FROM   pharmacies p
JOIN   pharmacy_staff_store pss 
  ON   p.pharm_id = pss.pharmacy_id 
GROUP  BY pharm_name
HAVING COUNT(1) > 3;
```

Also I wouldnt use `COUNT(1)` if someone change the order of the fields on db your query wouldnt notice and will show wrong behavior. Use `Count(fieldname)`

Comment: `COUNT(1)` counts the number of rows including `NULL` values (and is [identical to `COUNT(*)`](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245))- the count is on the number literal 1 (which is always countable) rather than the `1` signifying the value of first column. So the result will always be the same regardless of what order the columns are in.

Comment: Also `COUNT(fieldname)` will not count rows where the value of the `fieldname` column is `NULL` so it will not always give the same result as `COUNT(1)`.

Comment: No, that is not what I am saying. `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)` will count the number of rows (irrespective of whether any of the values are `NULL` or not) but `COUNT(column_name)` will only count the number of non-`NULL` values in that column.